# php 5.5 ldap_connect problems

Tags: php, ldap

Copied this script from php.net and put in an incorrect url.
For some reason this script does not die even when the connection details are totally wrong.

```
$ldaphost = "notaldapurl.com";  
$ldapport = 389; 


$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldaphost, $ldapport)
          or die("die not connect to $ldaphost");

var_dump($ldapconn);
```

The out put for this script is `resource(2) of type (ldap link)`

Additional info is that i'm running php 5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation...

> **When OpenLDAP 2.x.x is used, ldap_connect() will always return a resource** as it does not actually connect but just initializes the connecting parameters. The actual connect happens with the next calls to ldap_* funcs, usually with ldap_bind().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-connect.php